# Per user proxy - OS X 10.10

Tags: macos, osx-server

On 10.9 and previous we used MCX to manage proxy settings on a per user basis. (User level MCX).

This no longer works on 10.10 as MCX has been depreciated for some time now and I am surprised how much it still works in 10.10. So I have looked down the configuration profiles route but I can't see an option for it there either.

Any ideas?

OS X Yosemite (10.10.1)

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution (possibly temporarily), as part of our loginhook shell script I have entered the following:

```
UserName="$1"
UserGroup="$(sudo -u $UserName id)"
if [[ $UserGroup == *teachers* ]] ; then networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet <hostname> <port> off ; else networksetup -setwebproxy Ethernet <hostname> <port> off ; fi
if [[ $UserGroup == *teachers* ]] ; then networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet <hostname> <port> off ; else networksetup -setsecurewebproxy Ethernet <hostname> <port> off ; fi
```

Essentially it sets the proxy to a specific hostname and port with no authentication if they are part of a particular group. If they are not then they go to a standard proxy port.